# Set proxy for rubygems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, proxy

Is there a way to specify somewhere the proxy in rails projects so that I don't have to manually type it each time, like this:
`gem install --HTTP-PROXY http://web-proxy:8088 bundle`

I need to be able to type: `gem install bundle` and the proxy should be 'understood' by default. How can this be done? I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gem` will [use the `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable if set](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-environment). Just [set that in Windows 7](https://kb.wisc.edu/cae/page.php?id=24500) and it will be used by default.

Comment: Something a bit more specific or elaborate than this would be of great help, many thanks, Buck.

Comment: I don’t know what else to say. Set the `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable to `http://web-proxy:8088` as described in the second link. When you open a new terminal window, that environment variable will be set and `gem` will use it automatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Buck, it worked perfectly. I wasn't sure how to use the first link, but then I saw it's really great for theory. Many thanks. This saves me a lot of extra typing.

Comment: Great! Now if you accept my answer people will see that your problem question is solved.