# error with rails server command

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, windows

Can you point me to any good resources that show how to connect Sql Server to Rails app (Windows 7)?

I have done the following so far:
`rails new simple_cms –d sqlserver`

`gem install bundle`

`rails s`

after the last command, this error is thrown:

```
C:\Sites\s_cms>rails s
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:32:in `alias_method': undefined method `add_order!' for class `Class' (Name
Error)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:32:in `alias_method_chain'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter/core_ext/active_record.rb:14:in `singletonclass'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter/core_ext/active_record.rb:12:in `inc
luded'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter/core_ext/active_record.rb:145:in `in
clude'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter/core_ext/active_record.rb:145:in `<t
op (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:3:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-2.3.8/lib/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.rb:1:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-2.3.8/lib/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
        from C:/Sites/s_cms/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `block in server'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

PS: If I use sqlite as a database system, I am able to successfully start the webserver (no error). This probably means there's nothing wrong with my rails installation. I am guessing I might need to add sth to database.yml or write the database user and password somewhere. But how come this is not required with sqlite3?
I also found this resource but not sure if still applicable (it refers to rails 2.0, whereas I use rails 4.1.1) http://rubyrailsandwindows.blogspot.de/2008/03/rails-2-and-sql-server-2008-on-windows_24.html - and some of the things there I tried but don't apply.
Thanks in advance.

Later edit: I also tried `rails s` after editing the database.yml (from the config folder) to contain:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlserver
  encoding: unicode
  database: cms
  pool: 5
  username: guest1
  password: pwd1234%^&^
test:
  adapter: sqlserver
  encoding: unicode
  database: cms
  pool: 5
  username: guest1
  password: pwd1234%^&^
production:
  adapter: sqlserver
  encoding: unicode
  database: cms
  pool: 5
  username: guest1
  password: pwd1234%^&^
```

(of course, I also created previously a db called cms, and added a user called guest1 with the specified password, then made sure teh credentials worked to connect to the db by mimic-ing network connection from my local Sql Server itself)

After this new action I get a similar error as above:

```
C:\Sites\simple_cms>rails s
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-.1.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:32:in `alias_method': undefined method `add_order!' for class `Class' (Name Error)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:32:in `alias_method_chain'
        ...............
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug with `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter`.  It's being worked on but any fix has not yet been merged into a milestone.

It appears the workaround just now is to change your `Gemfile` to have:

```
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', git: 'https://github.com/Desarrollo-CeSPI/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.git'
```

Details of the issue are [here](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/issues/279) and the efforts to fix it are [here](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/pull/278).

Comment: Thank you so much, Graeme. I edited the gemfile as you recommended, then ran `rails s` once again. It prompted me to do a `bundle install` - after I try to run that, however, I get: `Fetching https://github.com/Desarrollo-CeSPI/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.git
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Desarrollo-CeSPI/activerecord-sqlserver-adapt
er.git/': Failed connect to github.com:443; No error
Retrying git clone "https://github.com/Desarrollo-CeSPI/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.gi
t" "C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/cache/bundler/git/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-a19f0
dc7902.....`

Comment: Could this be again because of the proxy? I thought I was rid of that after I set the HTTP_PROXY environment variable as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23607571/set-proxy-for-rubygems . I don't know how to force the bundle install to run with a proxy (syntax??) or if that is even the problem. Strangely, I am able to connect to https://github.com/Desarrollo-CeSPI/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.git by typing this address in the browser, hence why I think it could be a proxy thing again.

Comment: Could well be your proxy.  That fork does have a valid .gemspec so it should work.  Given you can access the repositary you might need to bring it down as a zip (unless you can `git clone` it) and build it locally.  Put it somewhere then run `gem build activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.gemspec` in that directory followed by `gem install <name of gem that was just built>`

Comment: I went to this page (https://github.com/Desarrollo-CeSPI/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter) , downloaded the zip file (`activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-master.zip`), then went to the root of our rails app , copied the unzipped archive there, ran the `gem build activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.gemspec` in that directory (called `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-master`) and the following error comes up:
`C:\Sites\activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-master>gem build activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.gemspec ERROR:  Gemspec file not found: activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.gemspec`
Thanks for all your patience...

Comment: Are you definately in the directory with the .gemspec file?  I just tried it on Windows and it worked - when it unzipped the file it was in a nested directory `C:\activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-master\activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-master`.  However I just went to the directory with the gemspec and typed `gem build a<TAB>`, using <TAB> to let it autocomplete the filename and be sure it was correct.

Comment: I wasn't playing in the right folder, sorry. I am so incredibly thankful for this, I was starting to get disappointed with the number of fixes required after installation and thought of switching to another dbms. Thanks so much, Graeme! Have a wonderful day.